# How to track the back-button of Android devices?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cocossharp

How is the proper way to catch the back button event in my CocosSharp game? Does it has to happen on the Android project or can it be done in the PCL core?

How is it done?

Comment: I think you need to do it in the Android project. You need to created a handler in your AppDelegate when you create the main activity: here's a [link I found](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44838/need-a-good-example-of-handling-back-button-press) which might be some help?

Comment: I think you can implement in PCL the [onBackButtonPressed()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.OnBackButtonPressed()/) method. This can be done in the XAML code behind in the PCL ContentPage.

Comment: No, but I don't look for a solution to this anymore. CocosSharp is a dead Shark. Thanks, anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As @ADimaano said, you could implment it in PCL by override the [OnBackButtonPressed](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.OnBackButtonPressed()/) method.

For example :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        //Do something
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is for simple Xamarin apps, however I'm talking about the engine CocosSharp that was created by the team of Xamarin and uses similar behind the scene mechanics. One thing CocosSharp does not have are Pages.